# Is there any way to see all the questions that are tagged with my favorite tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to visit http://superuser.com and I want to see just all the asked questions or all active questions that are tagged with my favorite tags.
I know I can search with one tag, but I want to search with all of my favorite tags in the same time .

Is there any way to see all the questions that are taged with my favorite tags ? What should I do ?

Comment: This should really be a tab at the top of every SE page IMO. #feature-request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a filter on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com). When signed in, go to "Filtered Questions":

[image]

You can then either bookmark your new filter or have it email you links to new questions. (And of course you can always access it from the Filtered Questions page itself.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [search](https://superuser.com/search) for this. Just enter two or more tags, using the bracket syntax. For example, searching for `[windows-7] [microsoft-excel]` will return all questions with both of those tags.

Comment: 1) I can find question that are not tagged with my entered tags. I searched for [windows] [microsoft] that it find [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/49825/does-microsoft-security-essentials-replace-windows-defender) that are not tagged with them. 2) it searches with google that questions are not in format and properties of the superuser site

Comment: @hamed If you search for `[windows] [microsoft]` **on the site**, you get  [these results](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows+microsoft). Not what you want, but what exactly nhinkle wrote, and it doesn't find the linked question.

Comment: @DanielBeck yeah, I had a mistake. but it still gets **AND** of the tags not **OR** .

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do _or_ on tags, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is a pre-defined filter, but it defaults to all of your SE sites.

Mine is: http://stackexchange.com/filters/114694/favorite-tags